# Is there an alternative meaning of "dated someone"

Tags: word-usage

When you say you dated someone, does it always mean you are trying to go out with someone (as in this implies something more than friendship) ?

Can I say I  dated my families and friends? Am I using it incorrectly ? Can it not mean a simple friendship thing ?

Comment: 'dating' does not mean friendship or family relationship, at all. It is entirely in the 'romantic' area.

Comment: @Mitch: that dates you.

Comment: So you can imagine what romantic relationship is present when I date myself.

Answer (score 5):

As a noun "date" means simply a social appointment (along with other meanings that don't concern us here). So you can "have a date" with a family member, a friend or a personal yoga instructor.

When used as a verb, "date" is almost always used to mean "conduct a romantic relationship". Dictionaries to permit the usage of "having a series of dates" (i.e. appointments) but it is very unusual.

So:

- "I have a date with my brother" is perfectly fine.
- "I dated my brother" will get you weird looks.

Comment: In my experience, "I have a date" still typically carries romantic implications, unless "date" is modified --i.e. "I have a date for lunch with..." or "I have a luncheon date with...".  It's also worth noting that "going out on a date" is also almost always romantic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as a verb it  generally refers to a 'romantic' appointment, for a more neutral or different kind of meeting you can make/arrange an appointment:

[Date](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=date) (verb);

> - "have a romantic liaison;" 1902, from date (n.3)

Date: (n.3)

> - "liaison," 1885, gradually evolving from date (n.1) in its general sense of "appointment;" romantic sense by 1890s. Meaning "person one has a date with" is from 1925.

(Etymonline)

[Date](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/date) as a noun has a more neutral meaning:

> - An appointment: *a luncheon date with a client*.

(AHD)

Answer (score 0):

People generally date themselves when they make references to antique culture, e.g. quoting from ancient television shows.
But it's possible to date others in such a fashion: "Hey Tom, tell Jeff that thing about the parrot you always go on with! What was it ... 'He's just resting'?"

Comment: I think that is not what OP meant :) Still beat me to a comment doing the same

Comment: Well, yes, but that is the alternative meaning of "dated someone" ;)

Comment: There's a joke along these lines, the punchline being "Cut him in half and count the rings!"